# Issue with subclassing UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am customizing a Parse login view and I created a blurred background with a library but now I can use UIVisualEffectView.  Since I had a class as a delegate for `PFLoginViewController` I decided to subclass UIVisualEffectView and make that my delegate.  The issue is that not all of my login view is showing.  I know that my frame is set correctly.  Here is my code for a better idea of what I'm talking about.

```
-(id)initWithEffect:(UIVisualEffect *)effect {

    self = [super initWithEffect:effect];

    [self setUpUserViews];

    return self;

}

- (void)setUpUserViews {

    NSLog(@"Setting Up View");

    CGRect size = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    //Initialize login and sign up views
    _loginView = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    _signUpView = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];

    //Set their delegates to this view controller
    [_loginView setDelegate:self];
    [_signUpView setDelegate:self];

    //Set fields for sign up view
    [_signUpView setFields:PFSignUpFieldsEmail | PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton];

    //Set sign up view for login view
    [_loginView setSignUpController:_signUpView];

    //Set up login view
    _loginView.view.frame = size;

    _loginView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [_loginView.logInView setLogo:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"]]];

    //Set Login Button
    [_loginView.logInView.logInButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.logInButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //Set login text color
    [_loginView.logInView.logInButton setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.logInButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //Set sign up button
    [_loginView.logInView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //Set sign up button text color
    [_loginView.logInView.signUpButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.6] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.signUpButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //Set dismiss button
    [_loginView.logInView.dismissButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.dismissButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [_loginView.logInView.dismissButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_loginView.logInView.dismissButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_loginView.logInView.dismissButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dismiss.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_loginView.logInView.dismissButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dismiss.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Set forgotten button
    [_loginView.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forgot.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forgot.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [_loginView.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_loginView.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //Use custom method for showing sign up view
    [_loginView.logInView.signUpButton  removeTarget:nil action:NULL  forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

    [_loginView.logInView.signUpButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(customViewMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Set up sign up view
    _signUpView.signUpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //Set sign up button
    [_signUpView.signUpView.signUpButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_signUpView.signUpView.signUpButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenPress.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [_signUpView.signUpView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //Present login view
    [self.contentView addSubview:_loginView.view];
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm getting.  There is an X in the top left corner.  That is part of the login view:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding break points in initwitheffect to make sure it's being called?

Comment: @Luke I didn't add a break point but I added that NSLog line and i know that it is getting called.  Also, I am getting the dismiss button of the view in the top left corner.

Comment: I would then just try not to subclass UIVisualEffecrView, and use another subview inside your UIVisualEffecrView as a delegate, as I had the same problems when working with direct subviews of NSVisualEffectView

Comment: But when I add my login subview to the content view then my delegated doesn't seem to be receiving calls to their delegation methods.

Comment: Have you verified that the contentView property is already initialized and not nil at that moment? Just an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.  The issue was that things were being released from memory too soon which resulted in there being a `nil` delegate.